# getdate has any special type (string, int)?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm including a page (FileA.php) that, on first load, should show data from this year (2014). In that page is a selector that allows to chose a different year, send the new year as post, and a handler php includes again fileA.php, but showing the data for the selected year.

My problem is that on first load nothing is shown, but it work OK afterwards (after the post). A stripped out version of the code (FileA.php) is as follows:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['Anio'])){
$today = getdate();
$_SESSION['Anio']=$today['year'];   
}
echo "<br>Anio: ".$_SESSION['Anio']."<br>";//for checking purposes only
```

The "working" part is selecting columns where the column name contains that year. A partial pice of code follows:

```
@mysql_select_db("mydb") or die( "Unable to select database");
mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");       
$query=mysql_query('select * from mytable') or die(mysql_error()); 

$field = mysql_num_fields( $query );
for ( $i = 0; $i < $field; $i++ ) {
    if (strpos(mysql_field_name( $query, $i ),$_SESSION['Anio']) !== false) {
        $names[] = mysql_field_name( $query, $i );
    }                   
}
```

Then I have a table that show the results, and a dropbox where you can select a year, and sends the selected year as a post to a handler php. Upon receiving this post, the original file (FileA.php) is shown again. The handler.php is as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['Anio'])) { 
   $_SESSION['Anio']=trim($_POST['Anio']);      
   include 'FIleA.php';
```

}

As said, once $_SESSION['Anio'] is "generated" in the handler.php after the post, all the code works OK. But on first arrival to the page, $_SESSION['Anio'] generated by getdate seems not to be recognized. If I echo $_SESSION['Anio'], it shows what seems to be a correct value (2014 on firts load, and the selected year afterwards).
Thinking that getdate() has a special type, I've tried

```
1.
$_SESSION['Anio']=(int)$today['year'];
2.
$_SESSION['Anio']=(string)$today['year'];
3.
$temp=$today['year'];
$_SESSION['Anio']="$temp";
```

Unluckily, neither of them work.
Does anyone spot the problem?

Comment: You are doing it wrong anyway – if you want to _display_ only specific records, then you should ask the database to only _give_ you those records in the first place … meaning: Use a WHERE clause in your SELECT statement.

Comment: You are using deprecated php functions mysql_* replace them before you continue with anything. It will be one thing you will not regreat.  Instead of mysql_* you can use the mysqli functions or the PDO class.

Comment: @Ronni: your right, I will change to mysqli as soon as posible. Can i mixed both functions whereas performing the shift?

Comment: @Cbroe: you are also right. I will improve the code according to your suggestion. Anyway, I think my problem will not be solved.

Comment: I see that you are using `mysql_field_name` here to compare the year against – so the year is not part of your _data_, but you have different _columns_ for each year? That would mean you should take even one more step back – and build a proper data model first.

Comment: @Cbroe: column names are actually the name of other tables, that include a year in ther name. So year is not part of my data indeed.

Comment: _“the name of other tables, that include a year in ther name”_ – that suggest _strongly_ that your data model is broken.

Comment: Maybe. Anyway, I don't know why if the variable is assigned with getdate is not recognized by the subsequent code, whereas when is assigned with trimpost it is. And in both cases echoing seems to render the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: it was indeed a matter of types. The code start working defining the variable as follows:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['Anio'])){
    $hoy = getdate();
    $tmp=$hoy['year'];
    $_SESSION['Anio']=(string)$tmp; 
}
```